# Ngfor in Material popup

Tags: angular, dart

How can I use the click attribute with divs created by ngFor in material popup ?

```
<material-popup class="menu-items-style" [source]="customer_table_menu" [(visible)]="row.showModel">

   <div *ngFor="let item of row.Buttons()"
     (click)="clickeddd(7)">

        <div >{{item['name']}} </div>
    </div>
    <div (click)="clickeddd(4)">clickkkxcxc</div>
</material-popup>
```

Comment: hello..  i am not able to call the function clickedd(7) with divs created in ngfor but i can call it with the div created alone , remark: i am using the ngfor in material-popup .. so any help please ?

Comment: would love to see a stackblitz where I can *run/reproduce*